# Or Where in Laravel Join

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, I apologize if my English is bad and I use Google Translate

In essence, I want to display buying and selling transactions in one data list, where the buying indicator is taken from the `invoice.company_id` column, and the selling indicator is taken from the `transaction.store_id` column.

Notes:

1. The `invoice` and `transaction` tables are interrelated.
2. The `invoice` table is used to store buyer profile data and payment details (such as account number, bank name, and others).
3. The `transaction` table is used to store seller/shop profile data and transaction status (Processing, Shipped, Received, and others).
4. In the `invoice` table, there is `company_id`, and in the `transaction` table, there is `store_id`, which essentially represents the same information retrieved from the `company` table.

Columns in the tables:

1. Invoice (id, company_id, account_number, bank_name, and others)
2. Transaction (id, invoice_id, store_id, status_transaction, and others)

--- Quick Account Flow:

- A = Buyer
- B = Seller

If the user (A) logs in, the query can use "WHERE invoice.company_id," and if the user (B) logs in, the query can use "WHERE transaction.store_id."

--- Challenge
The challenge arises when a supplier/seller can also make purchases from another seller. Therefore, in the transaction feature, I need to display both buying and selling categories in one dataset. Hence, I use the `orWhere Query` for the query.

Queries

```
$transactions = DB::table('transaction')
                    ->leftJoin('invoice', 'invoice.id', '=', 'transaction.invoice_id')
                    ->leftJoin('company', 'company.id', '=', 'transaction.store_id')
                    ->select(
                        'transaction.*',
                        'invoice.id as invoice_id',
                        'invoice.unique_code as unique_code',
                        'invoice.second_unique_code as second_unique_code',
                        'invoice.company_id as inv_company_id',
                        'invoice.status as status_payment',
                        'invoice.category_transaction as category_transaction',
                        'invoice.no_invoice as no_invoice',
                        'invoice.user_details as user_details',
                        'transaction_details.course_name as product_name',
                        'company.id as store_id',
                        'company.name as store_name',
                        'company.email as store_email',
                        'company.phone as store_phone',
                        'company.logo as store_logo'
                    )
                     ->where(function ($q) {
                        // Initialize
                        $tab    = request('tab');

                        // Validation for status
                        if ($tab == 1) { // Waiting Approved
                            $q->where('transaction.status', 0);
                        } elseif ($tab == 2) { // Being Processed
                            $q->where('transaction.status', 1);
                        } else {
                            $q->where('transaction.status', 2);
                        }

                        $q->where('invoice.company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)
                        ->orWhere('transaction.store_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
                    })
                    ->latest()
                    ->paginate(20);
```

However, when executed, the displayed data does not meet expectations. For example, when there are 3 data with different transaction statuses (Processing, Shipped, Received). When adding the filter status_transaction = "Shipped," the data in the processing status is also displayed.

Is there a way to display both data with an orwhere query? or do I need to create a new, better query?

I really need advice from everyone, thank you.

Comment: try using closure around your where clause, like `$q->where(function ($q) { ...your existing where clause logic for invoice.company_id and transaction.store_id});`

Comment: do you have sql query. so we can understand better

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it looks like better to start from the sql query then write the query builder. DDL, sample data, and expected output would be best provided. this way we can verify whether our suggestion work as intended or not.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. The question was answered by @Khayam Khan, and I have edited the question to make it easier for everyone to understand in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to group the conditions properly using parentheses to ensure the correct logic.

```
->where(function ($q) {
    $tab    = request('tab');
    $type   = request('transaction_type');

    // Validation for status
    if ($tab == 1) {
        $q->where('transaction.status', 0);
    } elseif ($tab == 2) {
        $q->where('transaction.status', 1);
    } else {
        $q->where('transaction.status', 2);
    }

    $q->where(function ($subq) {
        $subq->where('invoice.company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)
            ->orWhere('transaction.store_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
    });
})
```

In the original query, there is a mix of AND (where) and OR (orWhere) conditions. This means it will retrieve records where either the invoice.company_id is equal to the user's company ID OR the transaction.store_id is equal to the user's company ID. However, this will cause unexpected results when combined with the conditions related to the transaction status.

In the answered query, I introduced another where function inside the existing one. This new function contains both the conditions related to invoice.company_id and transaction.store_id. By doing this, it will explicitly group these conditions together. The purpose of the nested where the function is to ensure that the OR conditions (orWhere) apply to both invoice.company_id and transaction.store_id.

The corrected query ensures that the conditions related to the user's company ID are properly grouped, and it only satisfies the overall condition if either invoice.company_id or transaction.store_id matches the user's company ID, based on the OR logic within the nested where function

Comment: Thank you for your response; this works for me.

However, could you explain the differences between the query you corrected and the previous query? Because at first glance, it seems like just moving "orwhere" into the function.

Comment: sure why not. I will edit the answer to explain both the queries.